# Simple SQL Record Delete - Does not work

Tags: php, sql

All im trying to do is have a s simple text form delete the record from a sql database.
It returns that the record is deleted but it never actually deletes the record.

variablesremove.php:

[image]

html form image:

[image]

remove.php:

[image]

remove.php:

```
require('variablesremove.php');

$user = "#"; 
$password = "#"; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$database= "#";

$connection= mysqli_connect ($host, $user, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die ('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);

$deleterow = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber='$serialNumber'";

if($deleterow !== FALSE) {
    echo("The row has been deleted.");
} else {
    echo("The row has not been deleted.");
}
```

Comment: The variable that's holding the serial number is `$id` not `$serialNumber`. Check your sql delete string.

Comment: you dont run the query, or define `$serialNumber`

Comment: I fixed the $id 
$deleterow = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber='$id'";

Comment: Fix the serial number reference holder to $id and execute your query statement based on the example provide down below and you should be ready to go! @DouglasLittlefield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_query()` to execute your delete command.

```
$deleteRow = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $deleteRow)) {
  echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: mysqli_query($deleterow) = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber='$serialNumber'";  ?

Comment: Updated the example above

Answer (score 2):

```
...
mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);

$deleterow = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber = '$serialNumber'";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $deleterow)) {
    echo("The row has been deleted.");
} else {
    echo("The row has not been deleted.");
}
...
```

Comment: Please write a proper answer. Just slapping the code here is of little help at best or can be misunderstood and harmful at worst. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: If you check my answer was the only one that was not copied, all of the above put generic answers and were editing them, in fact I was the first to put the variable $deleterow in the correct function, while all other answers are generic. And one more detail the accepted response copied the $deleterow variable into the correct function after I post the solution.

Comment: Fair enough. If you want to get up-voted you will have to put in the extra effort of posting a good answer, regardless of others copying from you. Just trying to help out buddy. Check this discussion on this issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast
And just to show that I get your point I also up-voted your answer.

Comment: You are a great person, I thank you very much for your vote and I will consider all your tips, because you clearly value the good functioning of the site.

Comment: You can consider upvoting some of my answers on the way as well ;)

Comment: I gave two today and i will give more during in the week, if you can do this too i will glad. Hugs!

Comment: I'll look over your posts. I'll upvote good answers and questions. Take care :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as an example -

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM MyGuests WHERE id=3";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Error deleting record: Unknown column '00000000f5f409ce' in 'where clause'

$sql = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber=$id";

Comment: Integrate your DB

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be using a parameterized query to run this statement.

In it's existing form it is subject to SQL injection attacks.

```
if($deleterow = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber = ?") {
    $deleterow->bind_param("s", $id);
    if ($deleterow->execute()) {
        printf("The row has been deleted.\n");
    }else{
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else {
    printf("Error preparing the query: %s\n",$deleterow);
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Here is the working solution!

```
<?php
require('variablesremove.php');
$user = "#"; 
$password = "#"; 
$host = "#"; 
$database = "#";

$connection= mysqli_connect ($host, $user, $password);

if (!$connection)

{

die ('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());

}

mysqli_select_db($connection, "$database") or die ("Couldn't select the database."); 

$deleteRow = "DELETE FROM licenses WHERE serialNumber='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $deleteRow)) {
  echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```